# StorageException for azure blob with java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

When i am trying create container for my storage i get StorageException. 
1.I created azure account.
2.I created azure storage for blob
3.I wrotten simple test(below)
4.I made this code on local machine and got exception. What is wrong?

```
public class Test {
public static final String storageConnectionString =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;" +
                "AccountName=my_account;" +
                "AccountKey=my_account_key";


public static void main(String[] args) throws StorageException, InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {



    pushControll();
```

}

```
public static void pushControll() throws URISyntaxException, StorageException, InvalidKeyException {

        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();


        CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("observer");

        container.create();




    }
}
```

I get StorageException - >:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:89)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.StorageRequest.materializeException(StorageRequest.java:307)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.core.ExecutionEngine.executeWithRetry(ExecutionEngine.java:182)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.create(CloudBlobContainer.java:279)
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobContainer.create(CloudBlobContainer.java:252)
at ru.marketirs.model.Test.pushControll(Test.java:40)
at ru.marketirs.model.Test.main(Test.java:25)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

Process finished with exit code 1

What have i done wrong?

Comment: Your code looks ok to me. Please check for 2 things: 1) Make sure that the account name/key is proper and 2) Check the clock on your computer and see if it is running slow. These 2 things could cause the error you're getting.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your advice has worked. The problem was clock on my computer.

Comment: @GauravMantri 
Hi, I am having similar type of error while running war file. Can you please tell me how to solve the error by dealing with clock? What exactly have to do with clock? Our client is using windows 8 machine.

Comment: @GauravMantri try making sure the clock is synchronized with a time server. Any default server should be accurate enough for authentication - as long as the server is also configured correctly.

Comment: @GauravMantri , please see the link and help for the same : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44906619/how-to-run-war-file-on-machine-of-client-from-another-country-without-having-err/44906730#44906730

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok to me. Please check for 2 things: 1) Make sure that the account name/key is proper and 2) Check the clock on your computer and see if it is running slow. These 2 things could cause the error you're getting.

Answer (score 0):

**To by pass the proxy then please use like below, it works as expected and same has been tested.**

```
public class AzureUpload {

    // Define the connection-string with your values
    /*public static final String storageConnectionString =
        "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
        "AccountName=your_storage_account;" +
        "AccountKey=your_storage_account_key";*/
    public static final String storageConnectionString =
            "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;" +
            "AccountName=test2rdrhgf62;" +
            "AccountKey=1gy3lpE7Du1j5ljKiupjhgjghjcbfgTGhbntjnRfr9Yi6GUQqVMQqGxd7/YThisv/OVVLfIOv9kQ==";

    // Define the path to a local file.
    static final String filePath = "D:\\Project\\Supporting Files\\Jar's\\Azure\\azure-storage-1.2.0.jar";
    static final String file_Path = "D:\\Project\\Healthcare\\Azcopy_To_Azure\\data";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            //String storageConnectionString = RoleEnvironment.getConfigurationSettings().get("StorageConnectionString");
            //Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP,new InetSocketAddress("132.186.192.234",8080));
            System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "102.122.15.234");
            System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "80");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "ad001\\empid001");
            System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "pass!1");
            // Retrieve storage account from connection-string.
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);

            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();


            // Get a reference to a container.
            // The container name must be lower case
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("rpmsdatafromhospital");

            // Create the container if it does not exist.
            container.createIfNotExists();

            // Create a permissions object.
            BlobContainerPermissions containerPermissions = new BlobContainerPermissions();

            // Include public access in the permissions object.
            containerPermissions.setPublicAccess(BlobContainerPublicAccessType.CONTAINER);

            // Set the permissions on the container.
            container.uploadPermissions(containerPermissions);

            // Create or overwrite the new file to blob with contents from a local file.
            /*CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference("azure-storage-1.2.0.jar");
            File source = new File(filePath);
            blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());*/

            String envFilePath = System.getenv("AZURE_FILE_PATH");

            //upload list of files/directory to blob storage
            File folder = new File(envFilePath);
            File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
              if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                File source = new File(envFilePath+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
                System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName()+ " upload successful");

              }
              //directory upload
              /*else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());

                CloudBlockBlob blob = container.getBlockBlobReference(listOfFiles[i].getName());
                File source = new File(file_Path+"\\"+listOfFiles[i].getName());
                blob.upload(new FileInputStream(source), source.length());
              }*/
            }

        }catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Output the stack trace.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**.Net or C# then please add below code to "App.config"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
    </startup>

    <system.net> 
     <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true"> 
       <proxy usesystemdefault="true" /> 
     </defaultProxy>
    </system.net>

</configuration>
```