# How to run war file on machine of client from another country without having error related to clock/ signature?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, azure, blob

I have eclispe maven project based on Azure services. I want to run it on client's machine who is from another country, so have different time zone.

When I install eclipse on their machine and run all the services, those works fine. But when I added war to apache folder , after running it, it's giving error like :

```
Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
at com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException.translateException(StorageException.java:)
```

I came to this link and I think I am having almost same type of error :

[StorageException for azure blob with java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588168/storageexception-for-azure-blob-with-java)

Please tell me how to solve this and how to make clock 'slow' as mentioned in the answer of provided link.

Here is the code : (**See the code in else loop from first method. It's blob related code.**)

```
@Override
    public JSONObject syncFiles(JSONObject jsonInput) throws InvalidKeyException, URISyntaxException {
        if (jsonInput.containsKey("accountName")) {
            CloudFileClient fileClient = null;
            String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="
                    + jsonInput.get("accountName") + ";" + "AccountKey=" + jsonInput.get("accountKey");
            System.out.println(storageConnectionString);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject();
            ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                // fileClient =
                // FileClientProvider.getFileClientReference(jsonOutput);
                fileClient = storageAccount.createCloudFileClient();
                String directoryName = jsonInput.get("directoryStructure").toString();

                String[] directoryNameArray = directoryName.split("\\s*/\\s*");
                System.out.println(directoryNameArray.length);

                CloudFileShare share = fileClient.getShareReference(directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                if (share.createIfNotExists()) {
                    System.out.println("New share created named as " + directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                            .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                }
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.getRootDirectoryReference();
                for (int i = 0; i < directoryNameArray.length; i++) {
                    String directoryToCreate = directoryNameArray[i];
                    CloudFileDirectory directory = rootDir.getDirectoryReference(directoryToCreate);

                    String directoryNameToListFiles = directory.getName();
                    if (i == directoryNameArray.length - 1) {
                        for (ListFileItem fileItem : directory.listFilesAndDirectories()) {
                            boolean isDirectory;
                            if (isDirectory = fileItem.getClass() == CloudFileDirectory.class) {
                                System.out.println("Directory Exists Here");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("Name with files :" + fileItem.getUri().toString());
                                String downloadLocation = "/home/zcon/AzureDownloadedFiles";
                                String fileName[] = fileItem.getUri().toString().split("\\s*/\\s*");
                                for (int j = 0; j < fileName.length; j++) {
                                    if (j == fileName.length - 1) {
                                        String fileNameWithExtension = fileName[j];
                                        File f = new File(downloadLocation + "/" + fileNameWithExtension);
                                        String DownloadTo = f.toString();
                                        f.createNewFile();
                                        CloudFile cloudFile = directory
                                                .getFileReference(fileNameWithExtension.replaceAll("%20", " "));
                                        System.out.println("fileName===========" + fileNameWithExtension);
                                        String tokenKey = testFileSAS(share, cloudFile);
                                        cloudFile.downloadToFile(DownloadTo);
                                        fileList.add(fileItem.getUri().toString() + "?" + tokenKey);
                                        f.delete();
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    rootDir = directory;
                }
                ArrayList fileNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
                    String fileName[] = fileList.get(i).toString().split("\\s*/\\s*");
                    for (int j = 0; j < fileName.length; j++) {
                        if (j == fileName.length - 1) {
                            String fileNameReturn = fileName[j];
                            String[] fileNameReturnArray = fileNameReturn.split("\\.");
                            fileNamesList.add(fileNameReturnArray[0].replace("%20", " "));
                        }
                    }
                }
                jsonOutput.put("fileNamesList", fileNamesList);
                jsonOutput.put("fileList", fileList);
                jsonOutput.put("status", "successful");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception is " + e.toString());
                jsonOutput.put("status", "unsuccessful");
                jsonOutput.put("exception", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonOutput;
        } else {

            CloudBlobClient blobClient = null;
            String storageConnectionString = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName="
                    + jsonInput.get("blobAccountName") + ";" + "AccountKey=" + jsonInput.get("blobAccountKey");
            System.out.println(storageConnectionString);
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            JSONObject jsonOutput = new JSONObject();
            ArrayList fileList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList fileNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
            ArrayList blobItemList = new ArrayList<>();

            try {
                blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
                String directoryName = jsonInput.get("directoryStructure").toString();
                String[] directoryNameArray = directoryName.split("\\s*/\\s*");
                CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference(directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                        .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                if (container.createIfNotExists()) {
                    System.out.println("New share created named as " + directoryNameArray[0].toLowerCase()
                            .replaceAll("[-+.^:,!@#$%&*()_~`]", "").replaceAll("\\s+", ""));
                }
                // CloudBlockBlob blob =
                // container.getBlockBlobReference(jsonInput.get("directoryStructure")+"/"+jsonInput.get("fileToCopy"));
                CloudBlobDirectory directoryOfFile = container
                        .getDirectoryReference(jsonInput.get("directoryStructure").toString());
                for (ListBlobItem blobItem : directoryOfFile.listBlobs()) {
                    // System.out.println(blobItem.getUri());
                    // fileList.add(blobItem.getUri());
                    blobItemList.add(blobItem);

                }

                for(int  q= 0; q<blobItemList.size(); q++){
                    if(blobItemList.get(q).getClass()==CloudBlobDirectory.class)
                    {
                        blobItemList.remove(q);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(blobItemList);
                for (int l = 0; l < blobItemList.size(); l++) {
                    CloudBlob blob = (CloudBlob) blobItemList.get(l);
                    if (blob.getUri().toString().contains("Temp.txt")) {
                        System.out.println("Temp file was skipped");
                    } else {
                        String tokenKey = testBlobSaS(blob, container);
                        fileList.add(blob.getUri().toString() + "?" + tokenKey);
                    }
                }
                System.out.println("size of blobItemList is=============" + blobItemList.size());

                for (int k = 0; k < fileList.size(); k++) {
                    String fileItem = fileList.get(k).toString();
                    String fileName[] = fileItem.split("\\s*/\\s*");

                    for (int j = 0; j < fileName.length; j++) {
                        if (j == fileName.length - 1) {
                            String fileNameWithExtension = fileName[j];
                            String[] parts = fileNameWithExtension.split("\\?");
                            System.out.println("fileName===========" + fileNameWithExtension);
                            fileNamesList.add(parts[0].replace("%20", " "));
                        }
                    }
                }
                jsonOutput.put("fileList", fileList);
                jsonOutput.put("fileNamesList", fileNamesList);
                jsonOutput.put("status", "successful");
                System.out.println(fileList);
                return jsonOutput;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Exception is " + e.toString());
                jsonOutput.put("status", "unsuccessful");
                jsonOutput.put("exception", e.toString());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return jsonOutput;
        }

    }
```

Method to create BlobSAS :

```
@Test
    // @Category(SlowTests.class)
    public String testBlobSaS(CloudBlob blob, CloudBlobContainer container) throws InvalidKeyException,
            IllegalArgumentException, StorageException, URISyntaxException, InterruptedException {
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy sp = createSharedAccessBlobPolicy(
                EnumSet.of(SharedAccessBlobPermissions.READ, SharedAccessBlobPermissions.LIST), 100);
        BlobContainerPermissions perms = new BlobContainerPermissions();

        perms.getSharedAccessPolicies().put("readperm", sp);
        container.uploadPermissions(perms);
        // Thread.sleep(30000);
        String sas = blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(sp, null);

        CloudBlockBlob sasBlob = new CloudBlockBlob(
                new URI(blob.getUri().toString() + "?" + blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm")));
        sasBlob.download(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

        // do not give the client and check that the new blob's client has the
        // correct perms
        CloudBlob blobFromUri = new CloudBlockBlob(
                PathUtility.addToQuery(blob.getStorageUri(), blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm")));
        assertEquals(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.class.toString(),
                blobFromUri.getServiceClient().getCredentials().getClass().toString());

        // create credentials from sas
        StorageCredentials creds = new StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature(
                blob.generateSharedAccessSignature(null, "readperm"));
        CloudBlobClient bClient = new CloudBlobClient(sasBlob.getServiceClient().getStorageUri(), creds);

        CloudBlockBlob blobFromClient = bClient.getContainerReference(blob.getContainer().getName())
                .getBlockBlobReference(blob.getName());
        assertEquals(StorageCredentialsSharedAccessSignature.class.toString(),
                blobFromClient.getServiceClient().getCredentials().getClass().toString());
        assertEquals(bClient, blobFromClient.getServiceClient());
        return sas;

    }
```

Method to create shared access blob policy :

```
private final static SharedAccessBlobPolicy createSharedAccessBlobPolicy(EnumSet<SharedAccessBlobPermissions> sap,
            int expireTimeInSeconds) {

        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, expireTimeInSeconds);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        policy.setPermissions(sap);
        policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(cal.getTime());
        return policy;

    }
```

What changes I should make here?

Comment: Where exactly in your code are you getting the error?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by wanting the clock to run slow. But, keep in mind: you should be setting SAS (or policy) based on UTC, and you need to be cognizant of clock drift (that is, wherever you generate the SAS might have clock drift from the clock time in azure storage.

Comment: @GauravMantri , here is the error :  
Exception is com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

Comment: What I wanted to know which line of code is giving you this error. You have written so much code. Unfortunately it won't be possible to go through the entire code. So if you could update your question and tell us where exactly you're getting the error, that would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: @GauravMantri  It's giving error at : 
sasBlob.download(new ByteArrayOutputStream()); while debugging. This line is second part of code.  What's your suggestion? I think it's because creating a wrong policy corresponding with time.

Comment: And this code works just fine if you run it in Eclipse? You only start getting error when you deploy that as WAR. Correct?

Comment: YES, exactly. When I run it by eclipse on my machine or my client's machine who is from another country, it works fine. Also when I deploy war in my machine, it works. But..when I deploy war on that client's machine, it gives the error..What's your suggestion?

Comment: Just check the expiry date on the SAS you're using to download the file. I noticed that you're creating an access policy with expiry date so you can check that in the container's access policy. Other thing I would recommend looking into is the account key. Do make sure that your war file is picking up correct account key (to test, just try to list containers in the storage account using account name/key).

Comment: @GauravMantri  I have cross checked all the things.. everything looks fine..

Comment: @GauravMantri Have referred answer from Vyankatesh S Repal and that worked. Find the answer below and also make any updates in code if you have any different idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar problem before. What you need to do is , make your code comfortable for all the time zones like GMT,IST,EST etc. Because when you upload war in server of another country, your code must be 'clever' enough to understand time zone of that country !

So here is what you can do :

**Step 1:**

In third part of your code , try replaceing "UTC" by your client machine's timezone like GMT,EST etc.

If that works (and I am pretty much sure that it will work fine) , go for

**Step 2:**

First of all we will code something that gives you current time zone in String  like "Indian Standard Time" or "European Standard Time" etc.

Then, we will pick only first letters from all words and make a String like "IST" or "EST".

At last, we will pass this String at place where you wrote "UTC" in third part of your code.

So, here is the code :

```
private final static SharedAccessBlobPolicy createSharedAccessBlobPolicy(EnumSet<SharedAccessBlobPermissions> sap,
            int expireTimeInSeconds) {
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone timeZone = now.getTimeZone();
        System.out.println("Current TimeZone is : " + timeZone.getDisplayName());
        String x = timeZone.getDisplayName();
        String[] myName = x.split(" ");
        String s = "";
        ArrayList zoneArray = new ArrayList<>();
        char zone = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < myName.length; i++) {
            s = myName[i];
            System.out.print(s.charAt(0));
            zone = s.charAt(0);
            zoneArray.add(zone);
        }
        String timeZoneCurrent = s;
        String timeZoneDynamic = zoneArray.toString().replace(",", "").replace(" ", "").replace("[", "").replace("]",
                "");
        System.out.println("Value of S==========" + timeZoneDynamic);
        Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone(timeZoneDynamic));
        cal.setTime(new Date());
        cal.add(Calendar.YEAR, expireTimeInSeconds);
        SharedAccessBlobPolicy policy = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
        policy.setPermissions(sap);
        policy.setSharedAccessExpiryTime(cal.getTime());
        return policy;
    }
```

In this, timeZoneDynamic has values like "IST" , "GMT" etc. This logic must work. If have any error, post it in edit. Hope that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it is hard to tell, however there is a chance that the times on the client or at the server are not in utc or wrongly converted.

Check the time and timezones of the machine. If they match, check your code if the utc time or local time is used.

Comment: I have used UTC in code. What else to check for clock on machine?

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the issue was caused by the incorrect code in the method `private final static SharedAccessBlobPolicy createSharedAccessBlobPolicy` to get the UTC time via `Calendar` .

As reference, Here is my sample code to get UTC time using `Calendar`.

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance() ;  
// Get the time zone offset
int zoneOffset = cal.get(Calendar.ZONE_OFFSET);  
// Get the daylight-saving time offset 
int dstOffset = cal.get(Calendar.DST_OFFSET);  
// Reduce these offsets above from local time to get UTC time
cal.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, -(zoneOffset + dstOffset));
System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

Then, to add the expire time seconds to get the final date time.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. But still on my machine , it's giving IST and on client's machine , it's giving GMT. That's why, it's giving error at line while debugging: 
sasBlob.download(new ByteArrayOutputStream());

Error is : 
Exception is com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException: Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.

What's your suggestion?